# Question about Enigmas involutional property and its reduction of possible ciphers

Tags: enigma

I'm currently learning cryptography at a university. I can't wrap my mind around how the involutional property of Engima reduces its possible ciphers while being poly-alphabetic. Can someone please explain this?

The German Wikipedia [link](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_%28Maschine%29#Kryptographische_Schw%C3%A4chen) says that if the plaintext is ABCD, then the ciphertext CADB is impossible.

We're looking at all possible permutations of ABCD and apparently the only possible permutations are:

- BADC
- CDAB
- DCBA

Comment: Where did you find a reference about *ABCD* can't be turned into a cipher *CADB*? I looked (in the german version) and didn't find anything. Are you sure that you didn't misunderstood something? As far as I know it should be possible to turn the plaintext *ABCD* into the ciphertext *CADB*.

Comment: @AleksanderRas: I believe that he is referring to the transform of a single character (for example, the first).  That is, if a key turns an initial plaintext A->C, then that same key cannot turn an initial plaintext B->A; that is, it cannot do a mapping AB** into CA**...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of involutions of size $n$ satisifies the recurrence relation:

$$I(n) = I(n-1) + (n-2)I(n-2)$$

(This recurrence is easy to deduce).

Given than $I(1) = 1$ and $I(2) = 2$, we can easily compute $I(4) = 8$, which is strictly smaller than the number of permutations of size 4 (which is 24).

This recurrence allows us to quickly compute the number of involutions of size 26 as 158,432,124,870,784; much smaller than the number of permutations 26! = 604,937,191,689,908,372,404,961,280

BTW: the involutions of size 4 are:

$$ABCD$$

$$ABDC$$

$$ACBD$$

$$ADCB$$

$$BACD$$

$$BADC$$

$$CBAD$$

$$CDAB$$

$$DBCA$$

$$DCBA$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still don't understand, why for example ABCD can not be encrypted to CADB because of the involutional property, where is the conflict? 
Isn't there a conflict with the fact that enigma is poly-alphabetic, meaning the key changes slightly each encryption.

Comment: @Tim: actually, the plaintext ABCD *can* be encrypted to the ciphertext CADB; what can't happen is you have the plaintext A be encrypted to C, and (*with the same key*) have the plaintext B encrypted to A.